# sudo apt-get update change config files for puppet?

Tags: linux, authentication, puppet

I booted up 3 vm in linuxmint. 1 puppetmaster and 2 puppet. 2 days ago I could run "sudo puppet agent --test" in both of the client without a problem. Today I was installing meteor in one of my puppet. Afterwards"sudo puppet agent --test" no longer works. I am extremely perplex by this phenomenon. That is because I did not touch any .conf nor .pp in the past few days. As a matter of fact, I simply turn the vm off for 2 days and turn it on today. I am unable to diagnose the problem that's causing this error. I would appreciate if someone can give me an explanation and how to fix it.

Error log:

```
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: Server hostname 'puppetmaster' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetmaster.localdomain, DNS:puppet, DNS:puppet.localdomain, DNS:puppetmaster.localdomain
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Server hostname 'puppetmaster' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetmaster.localdomain, DNS:puppet, DNS:puppet.localdomain, DNS:puppetmaster.localdomain
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: Server hostname 'puppetmaster' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetmaster.localdomain, DNS:puppet, DNS:puppet.localdomain, DNS:puppetmaster.localdomain Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://puppetmaster/plugins: Server hostname 'puppetmaster' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetmaster.localdomain, DNS:puppet, DNS:puppet.localdomain, DNS:puppetmaster.localdomain
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Server hostname 'puppetmaster' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetmaster.localdomain, DNS:puppet, DNS:puppet.localdomain, DNS:puppetmaster.localdomain
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: Server hostname 'puppetmaster' did not match server certificate; expected one of puppetmaster.localdomain, DNS:puppet, DNS:puppet.localdomain, DNS:puppetmaster.localdomain
```

Comment: Probably you changed your /etc/resolv.conf so now `puppemaster` domain is being searched inside `.localdomain`.

Comment: In my puppet master my resolv.conf looks like this "nameserver 127.0.1.1" and " search local domain" Is there something wrong with it? I would appreciate if you can elaborate. I've been trying to fix this issue for 5 hrs.

Comment: Are you still looking into this?

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this by adding the below line to your `/etc/puppet/puppet.conf`

```
[master]:
certname=puppetmaster
```

Answer (score 0):

According to what you said in comments you may need to add an explicit

`x.x.x.x puppetmaster`  record to your `/etc/hosts` file.

Because you have `search local domain` in `/etc/resolv.conf` so if there is no explicit record in `/etc/hosts` it tries to resolve domain `puppetmaster.local` which is not what is in the certificate you have.

Comment: ^ I did it already. my /etc/hosts have 172.0.1.1 as puppetmaster. That's how I got puppet agent --test to work in the first place. However, after 2 days and reboot it doesn't work S=